# Discrete time embedded Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, stopping-times, discrete-time

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a (time-homogeneous) Markov chain with countable state space $I$ and transition matrix $P$ and assume $X_0=i \in I$.  Define the stopping times $T_0:=\inf\{n>0:X_n \neq X_0\}$ and for $k\geq 1$, $T_k:=\inf\{n>T_{k-1}:X_n \neq X_l \text{ for } l = 0,\dots,T_{k-1}\}$.  Assume all stopping times are finite $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. (so you can apply strong Markov property).

Is the embedded process $Y_n:=X_{T_{n}}$ a Markov chain?

So the process $Y_n$ is essentially the process $X_n$ with the removal of any states that it has already visited.  Now the future of $Y$ is not really independent of the past, given the present.  But its a bit weird because the stopping times take care of that....I am really unsure.

Comment: Your definition of $T_k$ is hard to understand.  I think the times $T_k$ are the times when the DTMC visits a state it has never been in before.  Perhaps you could say $$T_k = \inf\{ n > 0 : X_n \notin \{X_0, ..., X_{T_{k-1}}\}\}$$ Now, there is a problem that the $T_n$ values can stop being meaningful after a certain $n$, for example if there are only 2 states of the DTMC then what does it mean for $T_1, T_2, T_3, ...$?

Comment: Good point.  So since we are assuming all stopping times are finite, necessarily the state space I is infinite.  

I think this question is hard, which is basically what I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Even when the state space is infinite, this is not a Markov chain because it does not keep track of the history of previous states visited.  If I tell you $Y_n=8$, it does not tell whether or not I have already visited state 4. If not, then it is possible to have $Y_{n+1}=4$.  If so, it is impossible to have $Y_{n+1}=4$.

Comment: I thought that, but the way the stopping time is defined makes it impossible for $Y_{n+1} = 4$ if you have already visited state 4?